# URL Rewrites create compatibility issue with AjaxToolkit

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, url-rewriting, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using the latest AjaxControlToolKit v15.1.3 and using the ...

> ajaxtoolkit:calendarextender

for popping up the calender tool on click. 
everything works fine enough till there. now, when i add the URL rewrite code on the web.config file, the pop up on click no longer happens. any specific edit on the code i need to update for both to work. 
**Here is the URL rewrite code:**

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RewriteASPX">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Quite strange as long as showing popup does not require interaction with server. Do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: @MikhailTymchuk No, i dont come across any errors. it renders fine both with & without.....

Comment: So, I am guessing there is no solution to this.....

Answer (score 0):

AjaxControlToolkit is known to not work with URL rewrites.  This is because the AjaxControlToolkit generates two script files with .axd extensions at runtime: WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd.  Several references to those two .axd files get inserted in your client side HTML with huge strings of alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters as URL parameters.  Those references will fail when URL rewrites are used.  In my case, [and as outlined in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153195/403-forbidden-all-axd-files-aragh), the specific failure is a 403 (Forbidden) error.  The solution provided in that post worked for me, which was to remove all URL rewrites.  Hopefully that's an option for you too.